# laravel jetstream photo profile section doesnt apear

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

eh been trying to make the section of upload photo appear in the update section, but it does not appear unless I remove the if and I do not understand why I already modify the jetstream.php the .env and I do not know what else to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3o2m.png)
that if I do not know what it does but it is what does not allow the image to be displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2PsC.png)
the photo section does not appear :(

Answer (score 2):

To enable profile photo, you must enable the feature in your application's `config/jetstream.php` configuration file. simply uncomment the corresponding feature entry from the features configuration item within this file:

```php
use Laravel\Jetstream\Features;

'features' => [
    Features::profilePhotos(), <- uncomment this line
    Features::api(),
    Features::teams(),
],
```

Also don't forget to run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This is straight from the [Jetstream Docs](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#profile-photos) By the way.

Comment: i tried both but not working

Answer (score 0):

If profile photo section still doesn't appear after [enabling profile photos](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#enabling-profile-photos)

Try clearing the cache by running:

```
php artisan optimize
```

then refresh the browser.